# How to update a property which has a present in a property file?

Tags: shell

I have a property called WLS_HOME in my property file which has a path to my weblogic home. I need to replace this path with another path using shell script.

Comment: Are you talking about java like property file?  Then tools like ant has better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

sed 's/WLS_HOME/newpathto/g' filename> filename.replaced

Comment: or `sed -i filename 's/WLS_HOME/newpathto/g' `

Comment: @ EarlGray .  Thanks for the comment.  -i is new to me!